# MAUI WebView RTC Video stream on Android

Tags: android, webview, webrtc, maui, maui-android

Hello I'm trying to stream video from my Android phone Camera to the MAUI WebView

That is the approach:
I have JavaScript application where when button is clicked I'm asking for camera permission and starting a stream to the video element in HTML.

I'm loading this application in WebView with source and when I click the button to connect, nothing happens. My camera is not showed in the WebView. I'm seeing only this image:

I have these enabled in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

In the output console I'm seeing this line:

[CameraManagerGlobal] Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client

This is how I grant access to the camera when asked from JavaScript

```
 internal class CustomWebChromeClient : MauiWebChromeClient
    {
        public CustomWebChromeClient(IWebViewHandler handler) : base(handler)
        {

        }

        public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                request.Grant(request.GetResources());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the result: no video showed in the WebView
[image]

Comment: Did you request the camera permission as run time?

Comment: Do u mean this? await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();

Comment: Yes, can you show the code about the html or javascript to open the camera?

Comment: On the client side was really big mess. That was written by other team and i can't tell what exactly the problem was, but from the MAUI app everything was okay. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Did you mean the problem has been solved?

Comment: Yes. The problem was solved by the team who work on the Front End app(what i'm loading in WebView)